# Int too large to convert to C long while doing .astype(int)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm running a python script, where I have to convert a string column from a pandas `df` to `int`, using the `astype(int)` method. However, I get this following error:

```
"Python int too large to convert to C long"
```

My strings are all numbers in string format, up to 15 characters. Is there a way to convert this column to int type without this popping this error?

Comment: That error seems like a transcription of the real error. Post the original error.

Comment: An [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: The error is: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Comment: I had this error with this: `pd.DatetimeIndex(['1462352019029395103', '1462352019029395104'])`. It turned out that I had to use int64 instead of strings as timestamps. This is obvious, it just gave me the idea that you might also get this error simply because int64 is expected and you fail to to convert your input from string to int64 for whatever reason.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use `.astype('int64')`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': ['999999999999999','111111111111111']})
df['int'] = df['test'].astype('int64')
```

Comment: The issue is that with 15 digits, your numbers are too large for the integer type, which I'm guessing only uses 32 bits. You need 64 bit integers that way you can store numbers as large as 10^19.

Answer (score -2):

Check whether you are assigning a Large Integer values to variable.

1) Instead of applying multiplication, using power

For example:

```py
x = [10**i for i in range(1,1000)] instead of [10*i for i in range(1,1000)]  ,which will cross the variable limit
```